# 3-bit equality detector with sequential circuit T

Tags: circuit-design, clock, homework

[image]Design a consecutive 3-bit equality detector in 2 sequences with a synchronous sequential circuit. Each sequence is injected into one input of the circuit, so there are two inputs, A and B, where the sequences are synchronized in parallel. Only if the two subsections with the last 3 bits of each input are equal to each other, the output will be Y = '1'; Otherwise it will be Y = '0'.
The flip-flops of your project will be both of type T.

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Isn’t it your homework you’re asking us to do for you?

Comment: @user2233709 I do not want you to solve the problem, I need help getting started.

Comment: @user2233709 I know that a T-type flip-flop is characterized by the transition equation Qn + 1 = ~ T.Qn + T. ~ Qn. But I do not know how to implement this in the circuit. I do not even know where to start.

Comment: https://www.ee.usyd.edu.au/tutorials/digital_tutorial/part3/fl-types.htm

Comment: @JImDearden I know how to draw the T-scale, in fact we have to draw two scales like these. I do not know how to relate this to the sum of the two 3-bit numbers ...

Answer (score 1):

**A practical approach**: You can chain 2 T-ffs. There you have a counter that counts 0,1,2,3,0,1,2,... That counter can memorize how many equal bit pairs have been received. Need a XOR gate that compares 2 bits. As soon as a mismatching pair comes, the counter is reset. Need a gate that via another gate prevents the counter get more clocks if it has number 3. The same gate is used as output.

The practical way leads easily to unwanted results due the glitches caused by delays in circuits. Worse: It's not systematic. It's not easy to keep the idea clear and unchanged.

Another, diciplined and more formal way is to draw the state transition diagram of a synchronous state machine. The circuit synthesis is thatafter straightforward. Actually this surely is the wanted way.

Here's your state machine. Give names to the signals, decide when the T inputs should be 1 and design  a 3 input/2 output combinatorial gate circuit, the "Next State Logic". The ones and zeros inside the circles are your flip-flop outputs, the state variables.

[image]

In the elementary computing theory this circuit is an example of Moore Machine. Search for it! Your teacher wants you to create 2 gate circuits that give the T inputs to the flip-flops. Those 2 circuits are the next state logic . In the literature they are also called "The state transition logic"

Comment: I did the circuit and I posted with what I understood from your explanation. I did not understand in your drawing what Match was and I did not realize which circuit element represents the next state logic port and why XOR has the symbol = 1 inside it.

Comment: I also did not realize how we can make the circuit count in 3 bits to know if they are the same or not. We have two sequences A and B, how does the machine know it has to detect every 3 bits? For if it appears to the machine 4 equal bits how does the machine know that it has to reject the last bit?

Comment: @CarmenGonzález Match means "are equal". M is the name of the indicator signal and word "match" was given to explain what M is . M=1 exactly when A=B.  Symbol "=1" means "1 when A or B, not both =1". Tha ball inverts it.  4 last bits same in two sequences mens that 3 last bits must also match. No need to go away from the state 11 which makes the output =1. You wrote "both flip-flops" That means: 2 flip-flops. No more than 2 state variables are possible => max. 4 states => nothing more sophisticated is possible.

Comment: I did not catch the answer. Can not make the circuit without the Match as I posted? I did not deny XOR. I also did not realize what the "Next State Logic" box is and if that is part of the circuit. And I did not realize how the circuit knows that it only has to detect 3 bits at a time. Thanks for help

Comment: I agree that two flip flops give us states 00, 01, 10, 11.
I do not understand how the machine knows that it has to detect 3 bits that are 00 or 11. I do not understand how it knows that it has to do sequences of 3 bits and not of 2 bits or 4 bits.

Comment: Does the "new state logic" component fit anything on the circuit? Can I remove it when I present the circuit to the teacher? Or is it a physical component as a logical port for example?

Comment: I did not realize what "new state logic" is. Please, I really need help, I'm disoriented but I really want to learn and I'm trying very hard.

Comment: @CarmenGonzález it's a combinatorial logic circuit (=gate circuit) that has 3 inputs and 2  outputs. I adde it to my answer. If I had to build this physically, I woukd take 2 pieces of 8 input multiplexers, one for each T input.  The selectot bits of those multiplexers were M and the outputs of the flip-flops. Check, in what state variable and M combinations should make T=1 or equally , cause the flip-flop to flip its state.

Comment: Is not there any easier way to do it? My teacher never taught us the "the next state logic" and we never used Match. Are there no other alternatives?

Comment: @CarmenGonzález did he say NXOR or "State transitonlogic" If yes, use them. If not, go to the practical way. First construct a binary counter that has 2 control inputs U and W. W decides, if the counter should advance when the clock flips from 0 to 1. Let U=0 mean "no advance" and U=1 mean "advance" . W resets the counter to state 00 when W=1 and the clock=1. Add 2 gate circuits . One generates the U and one generates the W. Let U=1 when A=B and the counter has not reached state 11. Let w=1 when A is not =B. Your output is AND gated flip-flop otputs.. Note:clock=1 means A and B are valid.

Comment: A friend sent me this circuit in response to the problem, but I did not understand the reasoning. Could you explain, please?

Comment: I put the rest of the resolution in the forum.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55686/discussion-between-carmen-gonzalez-and-user287001).

Comment: I made the circuit with your indications and left in the forum. Could you see my resolution in the forum please? Could you please check that everything is all right? I was very grateful, it was a huge help, because I am a beginner and if you do not correct me already the mistake, I will do it countless times.